# Using wildcards to block GDrive sharing spam

Tags: google-drive, spam-prevention, google-drive-sharing, file-sharing

I'm victim of Google Drive file sharing spam. To block single users every time they share is unsustainable, because account addresses keep changing. They all come from `*.space`, so I want to block all users from that domain from sharing files on my GDrive. Is this possible, and how?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. It looks that this is something that should be sent directly to Google feedback. You could do this directly from the Google Drive toolbar, and click the `?` button then `Send feedback to Google`.